# Python ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Я новичок в Python и делаю дискорд бота (игру) и у меня возникает ошибка

Код:

```
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "/")
intents=discord.Intents.all()

debug = True

class Map:
    def __init__(self, map:list, blocks:list):
        self.map = map
        self.blocks = blocks

class Player:
    def __init__(self, icon:str, x:int, y:int, map, blocks):
        self.icon = icon
        self.map = map
        self.blocks = blocks
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def set_position(self,x:int,y:int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def collision_check(self,x:int,y:int):
        map = self.map
        blocks = self.blocks

        symbols = 0
        check = 0

        for element in blocks:
            if element.get("id") == map[x][y]:
                return element.get("collide")
            return False

settings = Map(map = ["█████████████████",
                      "█               █",
                      "█  ██████████████",
                      "█  █  █    █  █ █",
                      "█  █     █ █  █ █",
                      "█       ██      █",
                      "█████████████████"], blocks = 
                [{"id": "█", "emoji": "⬜", "collide": True},
                 {"id": " ", "emoji": "◼", "collide": False}])

map = settings.map
blocks_list = settings.blocks

def check_block(block:str, blocks_list:list):
    for element in blocks_list:
        if element.get("id") == block:
            return element.get("emoji")
    return ""

def print_map(map, player):
    text = ""
    for y in range(len(map)):
        for x in range(len(map[y])):
            if y == player.y:
                if x == player.x:
                    text += player.icon
                else:
                    text += check_block(map[x][y], blocks_list)
            else:
                text += check_block(map[x][y], blocks_list)
        text += "\n"
    if debug == True:
        text += f"Player: {player.icon}, X: {player.x}, Y: {player.y}"
    return text

player = Player("<:71:918467541431644210>", 3, 3, map, blocks_list)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Готов!")

@client.command()
async def move(ctx, *, move):
    if move == "w":
        check = player.collision_check(player.x, player.y-1)
        if check == False:
            player.set_position(player.x, player.y-1)
    
    if move == "s":
        check = player.collision_check(player.x, player.y+1)
        if check == False:
            player.set_position(player.x, player.y+1)
    
    if move == "d":
        check = player.collision_check(player.x+1, player.y)
        if check == False:
            player.set_position(player.x+1, player.y)
    
    if move == "a":
        check = player.collision_check(player.x-1, player.y)
        if check == False:
            player.set_position(player.x-1, player.y)

    await ctx.send(print_map(map, player))

client.run("TOKEN")
```

[image: Что я пишу в дискорде]

И потом возникает ошибка:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Us555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Us555\Desktop\client.py", line 102, in move
    await ctx.send(print_map(map, player))
  File "c:\Users\Us555\Desktop\client.py", line 68, in print_map
    text += check_block(map[x][y], blocks_list)
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Us555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Us555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Us555\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Comment: Ну где-то выход за границы списка. Проверяйте x и y. И map это функция питона, лучше её не перекрывать своей переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Новичку в Python настоятельно рекомендую сначала изучить Python, а уж потом начинать писать ботов и игры. А иначе так и будете на форумы бегать и задавать совершенно детские вопросы. Ну вам же явно английским по белому написали

```
text += check_block(map[x][y], blocks_list)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

И любой новичек в Python который потратил пару дней на освоение самых самых основ понимает, что в указанном операторе произошло исключительное событие -  попытка обратиться за пределы списка.  Скорее всего переменные х или y приняли значение, выходящее за допустимый диапазон. И происходит это скорее всего потому, что в предыдущих строках вы в y перебираете первую размерность списка map, а в x вторую. А в самом операторе х используете для работы с первой координатой, а y - со второй. И да,"map" в качестве имени своей переменной лучше не использовать.